# What are these type of electrical connectors called?

Tags: power-supply, connector

My new power supply has these pins. I know there is a connector that can install here, but I do not know what it is called. The DC voltage output and AC voltage input are different.

[image: dc power connector]

[image: ac power connector]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should refer to the [datasheet](https://www.cui.com/product/resource/vof-225.pdf) for the power supply. Here is one:

[image]

Check that the number of pins matches for the DC output.

Comment: In case you don't feel like paying $140 for the Molex KK hand crimper or $470(!) for the - I assume - intermateable JST VH hand crimper, JST sells pre-crimped jumpers with the terminal properly crimped onto both ends and you can just cut them in half to get two wires with terminals on the end.  You could *try* to crimp terminals with one of those "universal" "engineer"-type pliers style tools but if you are dealing with line voltage you don't want a bad crimp letting one of your wires come out of its terminal.

Answer (score 2):

The connectors look like (but its not) a [MTA-100](https://gr.rsdelivers.com/product/te-connectivity/1-640456-0/te-connectivity-mta-100-10-way-1-row-straight-pin/1320440).
I would say it is a [JST VH](https://www.rapidonline.com/jst-vh-series-3-96mm-top-entry-523652) connector:

JST B3P-VH(LF)(SN) 3 Pole:

[image: jst 3]

4 pole:

[image: JST]

There are also 6-pole ones, you can use those.

Comment: I checked the data sheet and they are  JST VHR type. I am having trouble finding these for sale online, however